# sitecore editframe button support multilanguage

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8

I have been playing around with `Editframe` buttons in a Sitecore 8 for a multilingual project and I have the feeling that Edit Frame buttons do not work properly on sitecore multilingual sites.

1. Were you able to get it working edit frame buttons with a multilingual implementation?
2. Is it working out of the box or do you need any special configuration?

My experience is that when I am on a localized page and I click on an `EditFrame` button, it will open the default language `Item` instead of the localised item. I am of the impression that this is what happen when you click on `Edit the Related Item` in the `Experience Editor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered your scenario very recently.

1. Were you able to get it working edit frame buttons with a multilingual implementation?

Yes, all the Fields I set up within the Edit Frame Buttons in the Core worked correctly with my Multilingual Site

2. Is it working out of the box or do you need any special configuration?

You need to add your Field Names into the `Edit Frame Button` Items in the `Core` database, found at the out-of-the-box path; `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons/Default/Edit`. Make sure your `sc:Edit` component references this path in the `Buttons` property

You may use different `Display Names` of the Fields for each of your languages for ease of use in the Content Editor / Experience Editor but as long as they are display Names it should be fine. If they are not and it doesn't work I recommend putting the `Field Name` for each language in the `Edit Frame` Item.

3. When I click on an EditFrame button, will it open the default language Item instead than the localised item, I am of the impression that this is what happen when you click on Edit The Related item as well

No, in both instances the Item will be loaded in the correct Language as well as when you create a new `Datasource` Item to be referenced by your `Component`.

The biggest issue that is present is when `Edit the Relating Item` and make changes to `Rich Text Editor` field or `TreeEx` field is that when you save it, it saves it to the default `en`language, even creating a Language Version for it if it does not exist.

I have raised this issue with Sitecore Support and they are currently investigating. When they have a fix I'll update you with their solution.

**EDIT**

The Support Patch to resolve the issue Edit the Relating Item saving changes to the wrong language version of the Item can be found here - https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/814090

Comment: HI Jonathan, many thanks for answering, quick question, witch version of Sitecore were you using? I am on 8 update 4.... It would also be interesting to know if you were using Glass MVC helpers to get the EditFrame buttons.... Do you have any language fallback module in place? My experience is that I cannot have different value for different languages for the edit frame buttons in the Core database...

Comment: Hi Stelio, I am using Sitecore 8 update 3 so I imagine there is not much difference if any, hope this helps

Comment: Sorry missed your following questions. The application we built is .NET WebForms and we didn't use Glass. Our implementation didn't require a language fallback like the Language Fallback Module, I don't think it would handle this scenario correctly sadly, but you should definitely raise it as a change request on its Marketplace page. Its expected that you can't have different language versions of the Edit Frame buttons in the Core, but as I mentioned above language it should work out the box, I'd be surprised if it doesn't but you can use Display Names or add the translated field names in

Comment: I have added the link to the patch to resolve the issue Edit the Relating Item saving changes to the wrong language version of the Item

Comment: Thank you very much for passing the link... on Sitecore 8 update 4 this is "breaking" the edit related item and my edit frame button functionality... I will keep with the investigation and wait to test it with the next sitecore release :)

Comment: No problem - Sitecore said they'll be working this fix into the next release. If your happy with my answer please mark it as answered for others to know

Comment: Jonathan a bird told me that this issue have been fixed in Sitecore 8.1.... it is still not 100% confirmed but I am optimist :)

Comment: Awesome news! Encountered this issue again during the week so glad it'll be fixed out of the box for 8.1 onwards :)

Comment: Actually https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/814090 has been updated on 1st September and the new hotfix is solving the problem

Comment: Yeah the Hotfix I linked to in my answer had the link to that article saying it fixed the issue for me back in August :)